# What does it mean to SQUARE the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy

$E=mc^2$

But what exactly does it MEAN to square the speed of light?  Like, what is happening in the universe at that point in the equation?

Comment: You could ask the same about $\frac 12 mv^2$. Or $e^2/r$. Squared quantities are nothing more than quantities multiplied by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

To get SI units of energy from SI units of mass, you need to multiply the latter by a squared speed. Nothing is happening in the universe. You could just as well choose units in which different constants appear. For example, theoretical physicists often use units in which the equation is just $E = m$.